# How to disable serial console in emulator?

Tags: android, mobile, emulation, mobile-development

does someone know how can I disable this serial console thing? I am new to mobile development so I'm not really sure what is this. When this was not there, the emulator was working super fast but after it popped up now the emulator is slow and laggy. Please help! Your help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May I know how you are launching the emulator? The serial console for the emulator gets enabled either as a qemu config parameter (not sure what the exact parameter is) or with the commandline parameter `"-shell"`.

Comment: I only wanted to disable it for performance purposes. But I figured out that the emulator was only lagging when I started it from VS code and was running smoothly when I started it from Terminal and Android Studio. So I'm okay with it now.